# Regex troubles in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I need this regex `=\\\"([^\\]*)\\\"` but Visual Studio tells me:

```
parsing "=\"([^\]*)\"" - Unterminated [] set.
```

But if I using this regex with space character after `\\` like this `=\\\"([^\\ ]*)\\\"` it works, but doesnt find mathes like `tag=\"String with space\"`.
Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What are you actually trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a regular string literal, so `\\]` means `\]` for the regex engine. Your string contains `[` (opening character class bracket) but has no closing one.

When you add a space, you just match a space with the character class.

To match `=` followed with a quoted string, use

```
var rx = @"=""((?:[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*))""";
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3d%22((%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*)*))%22&i=tag%3d%22String+with+space%22), and [an IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sQoLNJ).

This regex is declared with a *verbatim string literal* (so that we use just one `\` to escape regex metacharacters) and will also match all escaped sequences correctly.

If you do not need to match C-like strings with escaped sequences, just use

```
var rx = "=\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3D%22(%5B%5E%22%5D*)%22&i=tag%3D%22String%20with%20space%22) (I think it looks better with a regular string literal - too many double quotes.)